# how to get comments ,share and likes count of the post from linkedin using php

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

How to get Comments, Shares and Likes count of the post from linkedin Page using PHP

Using below code i posted posts on linkedIn Page,

```
include 'simplelinkedin.class.php';
$ln = new SimpleLinkedIn('ket', 'secret');
$ln->addScope('rw_nus');

if($ln->authorize()){

        echo "<pre>"; 
    print_r ($ln->fetch('POST','/v1/people/~/shares',
        array(
            'comment' => 'Hello Linkedin',
            'content' => array(
                'title' => 'test post',
                'description' => 'test post comment ',
                'submittedUrl' => 'http://www.google.com'
            ),
            'visibility' => array('code' => 'anyone' )
        )
    ));
}
```

for the above code i get key...

```
stdClass Object
(
    [updateKey] => UNIU-103511686-5821126484735057920-SHARE
    [updateUrl] => http://www.linkedin.com/updates?discuss=&scope=103511686&stype=M&topic=5821126484735057920&type=U&a=TpZB
)
```

Can anybody help me how to get Total Counts and Comments for the posts

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read LinkedIn's API documentation?

Comment: I'm not totally sure but I don't think LinkedIn has an API for this.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following URL, I am using this for my ruby client and able to get likes and comments count using the API, when i pass the share ID.

API Reference - http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/commenting-reading-comments-and-likes-network-updates